# How to call a predefined function and access the properties of a variable that is within that function?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Good Afternoon! 
I have a question about a function I created to draw rectangles on canvas.

The function is as follows:

```
function desenharRetangulo(x, y, w, h) {

  var ParametrosRetangulo = {
   texto: "",
   transparencia: 1,
   corRetangulo: "",
   bordaRetanguloCor: "",
   corFonte: "",
   tamanhoFonte: 12,
   retanguloLineWidth: 6,
 }

 ctx.strokeStyle = ParametrosRetangulo.bordaRetanguloCor;
 ctx.lineWidth = ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth;
 ctx.globalAlpha = ParametrosRetangulo.transparencia;
 ctx.fillStyle = ParametrosRetangulo.corRetangulo;
 ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
 ctx.strokeRect(
   x -= ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth / 2,
   y -= ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth / 2,
   w += ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth,
   h += ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth
 );
 ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.fillStyle = ParametrosRetangulo.corFonte;
 ctx.font = ParametrosRetangulo.tamanhoFonte + "px" + " " + "Courier New";
 textX = x + w / 2 - ctx.measureText(ParametrosRetangulo.texto).width / 2;
 textY = y + h / 2;
 ctx.fillText(ParametrosRetangulo.texto, textX, textY);
}
```

I would like to know how to access the variable "ParametrosRetangulo" and change the value of its properties when I call the "desenharRetangulo" function in other methods

Thanks for listening

Comment: You may, however, receive an answer at http://pt.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: sorry. I think it's Brasil stackoverflow. I'll edit.

Comment: @AlineVianna, you received some downvotes while the question was in portuguese, as well as 3 close votes... It's maybe a good idea deleting this question and, since you've translated it, posting the translation as a *new* question... starting afresh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to have `ParametrosRetangulo`as an optional parameter of your function.
So, in case you want to change its value outside the function, you just need to override the default parameter

```js
function desenharRetangulo(x, y, w, h, ParametrosRetangulo = {
   texto: "",
   transparencia: 1,
   corRetangulo: "",
   bordaRetanguloCor: "",
   corFonte: "",
   tamanhoFonte: 12,
   retanguloLineWidth: 6,
 }) {

 ctx.strokeStyle = ParametrosRetangulo.bordaRetanguloCor;
 ctx.lineWidth = ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth;
 ctx.globalAlpha = ParametrosRetangulo.transparencia;
 ctx.fillStyle = ParametrosRetangulo.corRetangulo;
 ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
 ctx.strokeRect(
   x -= ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth / 2,
   y -= ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth / 2,
   w += ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth,
   h += ParametrosRetangulo.retanguloLineWidth
 );
 ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
 ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
 ctx.fillStyle = ParametrosRetangulo.corFonte;
 ctx.font = ParametrosRetangulo.tamanhoFonte + "px" + " " + "Courier New";
 textX = x + w / 2 - ctx.measureText(ParametrosRetangulo.texto).width / 2;
 textY = y + h / 2;
 ctx.fillText(ParametrosRetangulo.texto, textX, textY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good resolution. I'll use that. =)